# Delphi-Xe5 Android Application send image data to MsSql Server

Tags: android, sql-server, image, delphi, delphi-xe5

I try android device on teke photo and send sql server.
I managed to do it, however i can not see posted image on my windows application.

mssql server 2008 and IMAGE Field Type is image.

I use android side : dbexpress. and Timage component. 
Take it photo and see timage (image1)

send server like this

```
SqlString:='insert into Photos (Description,IMAGE)';
SqlString:= SqlString+ ' VALUES(:desc,:img)';

// dataset : tclientdataset  and server side is DataSnap server.
dataset.CommandText:=sqlString;
dataset.params[0].DataType:=ftMemo;
dataset.params[1].DataType:=ftGraphic; // i tryed ftblob 
dataset.Params[0].AsMemo:=Memo1.Text;
dataset.Params[1].Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
dataset.Execute;
```

So far so good...

On windows application i use tdbmiage. but after open dataset raise error invalid image type (dbimage1)

I try another way windows side on devexpress cxdbimage.
Its multiple format image component.
But not see image.

I try windows app side cximage load bmp or jpg and post.
And compare db field in management studio, android post record row and windows post record row. Does not look like rows.

I think, i need to before send data, in convert android application.

I cannot find problem.
How can i do ?

Thank you for your interest and sorry for my bad English...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19116789/937125