# Delphi save packed record as blob in a sql database

Tags: sql, delphi, parameters, blob, ado

I need to save a packed record to a database that I connect with using ADO. It is easy to do this with an ADOTable using CreateBlobStream but I need to do it using a SQL UPDATE/INSERT query. The closest solution I have found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103437/delphi-load-image-save-as-blob-in-a-sql-database). However, unlike a TJpegimage, you cannot assign a packed record to a parameter because it is not a TPersistent object. How can I get this code to work?

```
type
  TMyRecord = packed record
    FontName: string[30];
    FontSize: word;
    FontColor: integer;
    FontStyle: word;
    Attachement: string[255];
    URL: string[255];
  end;
var
  MyRec: TMyRecord;
begin
  //assume MyRec populated here
  DMa.qry1.SQL.Text:= 'INSERT INTO my_table (blob_field) VALUES(:rec_data)';
  DMa.qry1.Parameters[0].Assign(MyRec);
  DMa.qry1.ExecSQL;
end;
```

A proposed solution was to save the record to a stream and load that into the parameter. This however results in a "data type mismatch in criteria expression" error.

```
  stream := TMemorystream.Create;
  try
    Stream.Write(MyRec, SizeOf( MyRec));
    DMa.qry1.Parameters[0].LoadFromStream(Stream,ftBlob);
    stream.Position := 0;
    DMa.qry1.ExecSQL;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: `Assign` is for copying parameter objects, not for value assignment. You can save your record into a stream simply by `Stream.WriteBuffer(MyRec, Sizeof(MyRec));`.

Comment: Right @TLama but how do you read the stream into the parameter.

Comment: @David Heffernan, if you carefully read my question you'll see it is not a duplicate that you believe it is. The answer you provided is similar to the answer I referenced.

Comment: That `Stream` can be a blob stream that you create for the parameter (`CreateBlobStream` can create that stream).

Comment: But CreateBlobStream requires a field in a dataset. INSERT queries have no fields.

Comment: Call `LoadFromStream` on the parameter and pass a stream and `ftBlob`. As per the accepted answer in the dupe.

Comment: This gives a "data type mismatch error".

`    stream := TMemorystream.Create;
    try
      Stream.Write(MyRec, SizeOf( MyRec));
      DMa.qry1.Parameters[0].LoadFromStream(Stream,ftBlob);
      DMa.qry1.ExecSQL;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;`

Comment: I guess you've got some debugging to do now. Don't you need to move the stream's position back to the beginning?

Comment: Moving the stream position back to the beginning has no effect, same error.

Comment: So continue debugging.

Comment: @David Heffernan, your "solution" doesn't work. I've proven that. It also proves that this is a new question that has never been asked here before, proving that you were wrong to flag it as a duplicate question.

Comment: No. That's not so. That you are not able to get the code right does not make this a different question from the (numerous) duplicates that already exist.

Comment: Why are you setting position to zero after you have read from the stream?

Comment: I already told you resetting the position has no effect. I am trying to save a record not an image. This is a new question. If there was a problem with the code it would be obvious and you could point it out. Your "solution" may work for saving images but it clearly doesn't work for records.

Comment: Although it's unlikely to make a difference to your problem (because of the ADO layer in between), what Sql back-end are you using, Sql Server or what?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I have a working & tested Insert + Select example including DDL Sql which might allow the OP to spot the difference, if only I could post it.  I see there are 4 re-open votes ...

Comment: @MartynA I'm testing with Access but need it to work with MS SQL and MySQL as well.

Comment: Well, at the risk of stating the obvious, there must be some difference between between your situation and mine which allows mine to work.  The difference is possibly in some non-obvious detail (not necessarily in the Delphi code), which it would be useful to identify.  So, let's hope the Duplicate flag gets cleared.

Comment: @Martyn Post the answer at the dupe?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I could, I suppose, but seems to me that there is more likely to be something "environmental" involved in the OP's prob.  Which makes it different from the subject of the other thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Maybe not, but if the OP's code ought to work but doesn't, then surely there is useful info for future readers in establishing what it is that makes the difference (e.g. database back-end, MDac version, Delphi ADo Component or whatever).  Anyway, I've followed your suggestion and pro tem posted my answer to the linked q.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Btw, I don't think my "answer" is a good fit with the linked q, because that was specifically about storing graphic data in a blob field, which is handled in Delphi differently than vanilla blobs.  So, I don't think the question is the same as the OP's here.

Comment: @Martyn Asker could ask a specific Q about their environmental problem

Comment: I was wrong with the `CreateBlobStream`, my mistake, but this task is as simple as writing the record into a temporary stream which you load into a parameter stream. Nothing more than that. I don't see anything environment specific here. All that should be handled by the ADO abstraction.

Comment: @TLama:  "should be handled" - Indeed.  Perhaps the OP will be able to tell us where the facts diverged from the theory.

Comment: @Martyn If that happened it could be a new Q, or this one reopened. As it stands I can't see any reason for this not being a dupe.

Comment: @fullerm You are not saving a record or an image. It's a binary blob. The content is irrelevant.

Comment: At first I thoght your problem is related to the fact that you are testing with MS-Access (you mentioned this only in your comments). but testing the duplicate code (with TMemorystream) against  MS-Access works with no problems. so you need to give more details/specifications, and show the entire code/DDL so it could be reproduced.